# FlatFileParseException Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, filereader

I am getting flat file parse exception when i use FlatFileItemReader in my job configuration.

Actually it was working fine, but with recent files its throwing error.

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[URL [file:/prod/users/cdi/crh537/Java_All/input/xaaaaa]], input=[16910203315393417SEVAN Q DANG18711 PARK GROVE LNDALLASTX7528751224609645044438000VANVETTE98@YAHOO.COM586404562MAR CL197311192013042504Closed (zero balance DDA)220PUSA]
```

The main difference is current file records contains some special characters like @ and ().

The following line throws the error. The delimiter used is ^A (linux)

```
16^A123^A2323232^ADD^SWAN D REE^A123 MMM STRRET^A^ADALLAS^ATX^A2222^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A434343434^A23232^A^AABC@ABC.COM^A586404562^A^A^AMAR^A ^ACL^A121212^A20130425^A04^AClose^A^A220^A^A^AP^AUSA^A
```

The following is the reader configuration.

```
<bean id="masterFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

        <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fileResource']}" />

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="${file.delimiter}"/>
                        <property name="names" value="filed1,field2,...field39" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="com.batch.SrcMasterFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you share your full stack trace?

Comment: Actually the issue was the record ending with ^A$ so, its considering one extra token(expected 39 , actual 40).. Thanks for the detail stack trace which i somehow missed in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have hidden characters in your file. You can follow [this link](http://linuxaria.com/pills/linux-terminal-seeing-the-unseen-characters-with-cat?lang=en) instructions to verify if and which characters you have in your file.

This question can help you [\001 delimiter issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744449/spring-batch-flatfileitemreader-001-delimiter-issue) regarding choosing right value for delimiter. As suggested you can try to pass `"\u0001"` instead `^A`.

**Update:**

The actual error was when printed the entire stack trace **org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 39 actual 40**

Its because the last field in a record/line followed by delimiter and $ not just $, so there is one extra token.

Comment: Thanks @Nenad.. I will look into the links and let you know. BTW i am passing "\u0001" as delimiter in my code.

Comment: Maybe you can also put whole stack trace since `FlatFileItemReader` is wrapping exception from `LineTokenizer` and it holds actual error which might help in resolving issue.

Comment: Probably exception from `LineTokenizer` held exception that it expected 39 tokens but had 40, maybe you might add it to your post so when somebody finds this posts they will have easier time knowing what was wrong.

Comment: Yes @Nenad... when i print the whole stack trace the actual error was org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 39 actual 40.... But FlatFileItemReader wrapping that exception and gives some commong parsing exception.

Comment: Yeah I know but might be good for future readers of this question to edit your answer and add that exception, was just suggestion. Not many people read this comments.